# update fields of created object django in one go

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to update the get_or_create object. I don't know if there is any simple way.

**myapp/models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class MyModel(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_len=5)
    valid = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    relevant = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    use = models.CharField(max_len=10)
    date = models.DateField('date', null=True, blank=True)
```

**myapp\management\commands_my_command.py**

```
from myapp import MyModel


my_obj_defaults = {'valid': False, 'relevant': False, 'use': 'useless'}
my_obj, created = MyModel.get_or_create(code=mycode, defaults=my_obj_defaults)

if created:
    my_obj.save()
else:
    my_obj.update(**my_obj_defaults)
```

It is giving `AttributeError: 'MyModel' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: Not related, but I think you should do `my_obj.update(**my_obj_defaults)`

Comment: What additional functionality are you adding that `objects.get_or_create` does not provide?

Comment: Isn't `update()` used for queryset returned by filter ?

Comment: @IainShelvington I am new to `django models`. In my case, I think get_or_create will either get or create but what if you want to update if get?

Comment: @Moha369 Yes, I think so too. Django's `Model` does not have an attribute `update`

Comment: He should use `update_or_create()` or assign attribute manually like `my_obj.valid = False` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) takes an argument `defaults` and will set those values on an existing record or on a created record. This is I think what you are trying to replicate?

```
my_obj_defaults = {'valid': False, 'relevant': False, 'use': 'useless'}
my_obj, created = MyModel.objects.update_or_create(code=mycode, defaults=my_obj_defaults)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't knew this.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```py
my_obj_defaults = {'valid': False, 'relevant': False, 'use': 'useless'}
my_obj, created = MyModel.get_or_create(code=mycode)
for k, v in my_obj_defaults:
    setattr(my_obj, k, v)
```